# can't find module webpack.dev.js in cornerstone 2.0

Tags: bigcommerce

Bigcommerce has released the new cornerstone theme version 2.0 and I use it for the store development but whenever I fire stencil start command, it gets the error and the error you can see below

```
    module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './webpack.dev.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\cornerstone\stencil.conf.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue on our end, fixed in the 2.1 release. You can download Cornerstone 2.1 here:

https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/releases/tag/2.1.0

You'll also want to make sure you've updated Stencil CLI to version 1.15.0.

Comment: Thanks, Karen. I have also found the issue, there were missing 3 files so I have put them.
1. webpack.common.js
2. webpack.dev
3. webpack.prod